# Is there a C# "Library Of Objects" website?

Tags: c#

If I need a regular expression, I can go to regexlib.com and with a bit of luck, find a regular expression for my requirement.

If I need a class for, say "Employee", is there a centralised resource out there where I can just grab the code for a sample Employee object? I say Employee here as a simple example; another example might be "Manufacturer", "Car" and "Car Model".

It's a deceptively difficult thing to search for as all the keywords I could think of are in use in C# and OOP already.

Just wondering as I was about to roll a "Phone" object and thought that surely there must be one already out there for something as mundane as that. If there is, I don't see it.

Cheers,

Richard

Comment: what makes you think an Employee or Car class "out there" is going to fit your own application's requirements? do you also intend to utilise whatever base interface, service layers, and framework they inherit?

Comment: I agree with @icelava - even if you do find an implementation that looks promising, you'll probably spend just as much time (or more) tweaking it to fit into your application scenario than if you simply wrote it from scratch. If these classes are something you'll need across multiple apps, then you could create your very own library one time for reuse. Good luck@

Comment: Agree with above comments. You find code out there to re-use common logic, helpers, extensions, etc. But domain model's should be rolled by the expert (you), not swayed by other people's implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wanted to roll some demos and didn't fancy doing it myself for that purpose. Of course, normally I'd do it but for simple demos I wanted to shave off some time. No worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to Google.com and search for "<class name>.cs" to see what implementations are out there.

- (Example) http://code.google.com/query/#q=Employee.cs

Comment: You're right, I'd already thought of that. But what I want is an object with some surety that it reflects best practice. No biggie for a simple object but if there's all sorts of multiple inheritance going on, I'd want to be sure the code was good before using it :)